# symfony3 vendor's console commands not available

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-console, symfony-3.2

I just created a new symfony3.2.6. project and added a few vendors (FOS User Bundle, Propel2 and Twig) but no new console seem to be available. At least I do not see any of them when using 'app/console' or 'bin/console' command.

/app/autoload.php is loaded from the console-file which also seems to load the /vendor/autoload.php file.

Are you able to give me a hint on what I might have done wrong?

Thanks a lot!
Steffen

Comment: Did you add them to the bundles in `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: Hi. I found the mistake - didn't install the propel-bundle but only propel2. Now I have the problem that for my symfony-version there doesn't seem to be a propel-bundle version available (https://packagist.org/packages/propel/propel-bundle). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. The problem was a wrong version-requirement description on packagist.org THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!!